# What is the best Augmented Reality Environment to use to develop mobile app?

Tags: augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I need to develop a prototype of an augmented reality app for research purpose.
This is my first time with augmented application and I only have basic knowledge on android.

The application is an android application that uses video overlay to display over the scene after detecting a target.  The only problem is that the videos are obtained from another user (through another application that will allow user to record a video). The tutorials and examples I found allow you to attach the video to the target by developer not the the user and that's not my case.

Since either way I have to invest sometime to learn how to develop it. Whats you recommended environment? Android studio with **Vuforia. Vuforia with unity ? or other SDK? and I would appreciate if you have a slimier tutorial and samples.

It just a prototype  therefore I'm not looking for high quality. Easy and less time consuming is my interest.

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity 3D with Vuforia is easier for a beginner to understand. For more advanced functions you might want to use the Android Studio. I am not sure about how the user can attach a video to the target since normally, the developer has to include the video file in the Assets folder to attach it to target. This is how it is done in Unity. I hope someone can give you a better insight into this. But, I have worked with Unity/Vuforia and it is a pretty comfortable and easy environment for a beginner. All the best for your prototype :)

Comment: Thank you ! I will try it get more familiar hopefully I will find a way